# Eigenvectors Always Contained in Nullspace of T-$\lambda$I

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to Prove Below Theorem?

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a vector space $V$, and let $ \lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $T$. A vector $v \in V$ is an eigenvector of $T$ correspoidng to $\lambda$ iff $v \neq 0$ and $v\in N(T-\lambda I)$.

Answer (score 5):

Try writing out the definitions every time attempting these kind of problems:

$\lambda$ eigenvector of $T$ iff exists $v\not =0 $, $Tv = \lambda v $ iff exists $v\not= 0$, $(T- \lambda I)v = 0$ iff exists $v \not=0$,  $v \in N(T-\lambda I)$.

Comment: what do you mean by $Tv$? are they multipliable? I mean $T(v)$ would make sense to me but not $Tv$

Comment: @jackerysmith If $T$ is a linear operator, we usually write $Tv$ instead of $T(v)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider $0 \neq v$ be an eigen vector corresponding to an eigen value $\lambda.$ Then $Tv = \lambda v$ which implies $(T - \lambda I)v = 0.$ Hence $v \in N(T - \lambda I).$